# Read words until user writes 'end', then, order lexicographically(as in a dictionary), show the last word

Tags: java, string, lexicographic

User will enter words until the last word written is "end", then the code has to order lexicographically, as we have in a dictionary, all the words entered before 'end' and print the last word, the one classified the last.

//.....

```
    Scanner word = new Scanner (System.in);
    String keyword="end";
    String finalstring;

    String[] firststring= new String[1000]; //Don't know how to stablish a //dynamic string[] length, letting the user stablish the string[].length  
    for(int c=0;c<firststring.length;c++){
        firststring[c]=word.next();
        if(firststring[c].equals(keyword)){
            finalstring=firststring[c].substring(0,c);
            c=cadena.length-1; //To jump out of the for.
        }
    }
    for (int c=0;c<finalstring.length();c++) {
        for(int i=c+1;i<finalstring.length();i++) {
            if (firststring[c].compareTo(firststring[i])>0) {
                String change = firststring[c];
                firststring[c] = firststring[i];
                firststring[i] = change;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\nYou entered "end" and the last word classified is "+finalstring[finalstring.length()-1]); //Of course, error here, just did it to put one System.out.print of how should the result be.
}
```

}

This is what I tried, though, without any type of success, any help of yours will be a big help, thank you ALL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Don't know how to stablish a dynamic string[] length, letting the user establish the string[].length

It is not necessary to do that.  But here's how.

Approach #1: ask the user to give you a number and then allocate the array like this:

```
String[] strings = new String[theNumber];
```

Warning: the requirements don't say you are allowed to do that, and you may lose marks for deviating from the requirements.

Approach #2: use an `ArrayList` to accumulate a list of words, the use List.toArray to create an array from the list contents.  (Read the javadocs for list to work it out.)

---

> Of course, error here, just did it to put one System.out.print of how should the result be.

Yea.  One problem is that the `length` is 1000, but you don't have 1000 actual strings in the array.  The same problem affects your earlier code too.  Think about is ...

---

I'm not going to fix your code to make it work.  I've given you enough hints for you to do that for yourself.  If you are prepared to put in the effort.

One more hint: you can / should use `break` to break out of the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

I know some words are not in English but in Catalan, but the code can be perfectly understood, yesterday I finally programmed this answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escriu les paraules que vulguis, per acabar, usa la paraula 'fi'.");
    String paraules = "";
    int c=0;
    do {
        String paraula = entrada.next();
        if (paraula.equals("fi")) {
            c++;
        } else {
            if (paraula.compareTo(paraules) > 0) {
                paraules = paraula;
            }
        }
    } while (c==0);
    System.out.println("L'última parala ordenada alfabèticament és "+paraules+".\n");
}
```

}